# Automated rendering in after effects

Tags: after-effects, automation

I have a project with a temporary audio file. I use [Soundkeys from Trapcode](http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-sound-keys/) to create a visualizer. I need to render the project automatically and change the audio file to some other file every time, changing the visualisation. I already googled and came to Dataclay's Templater 2, but this software is expensive and I an still a student.

So my question is: Is there a way to change media in an after effect project and send it to media encoder to render it from the command line?

Comment: So, did you just try what happens if you replace the audio track?

Comment: @HansMeiser I did try to change the audio file but my video didn't change. I use soundkeys from trapcode for the visualizer.

Comment: Well, maybe it caches to waveform data from the audio...  Did you also try "replace footage" function on the file or just replace the audio without re-reading it explicitly within AE?

Comment: And... Are you on Mac or Pc? Because I guess on Mac you could try to automate this via applescript / automator...

Comment: @HansMeiser I have set up after effects on windows server 2012R2

Comment: Ok, I guess you can replace footage using expressions in AE, take a look here: https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/227/20765

Comment: Or, even better, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396499/after-effects-script-for-replacing-footage

Comment: Probably your question is a duplicate to the last one I posted?

Comment: @HansMeiser Is it possible to replace footage from the command line?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the concept of expressions, here is an introduction: http://www.schoolofmotion.com/after-effects-expressions-101/

Comment: And here about the concept of startup / shutdown scripts: https://www.editingcorp.com/after-effects-scripts-startup-shutdown/

Comment: Here is a snippet on how to replace footage by a script: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/873561?tstart=0

Comment: @HansMeiser After Effects scripts ≠ expressions. Expressions can't replace footage items, change the project or be run from the command line, but Extendscript can.